# Writing Nb whitespace character in C

Tags: c, whitespace

I am just wondering how to write a certain number of whitespace character in C.
For instance, if I would like to write *size* whitespace character in a file descriptor, I would write something like this :

```
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0600);

    ....   

 char* spaces = malloc(strlen(f2));
 memset(spaces,' ', size);

 if(write(fd, sentence1, size) == -1){
   perror("Error1 while writing in the file");
   fprintf(stderr, "Error[%s, %s] : %s\n", sentence1, filename, strerror(errno));
   return EXIT_FAILURE;  
 }

 ...

 if(write(fd, spaces, strlen(f2)) == -1){
  perror("Error2 while writing in file");
  fprintf(stderr, "Error[%s]:%s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }

 free(spaces);

 ....
```

I got an error in the write function. Can somebody tells me what is wrong with my code and how can I resolve this problem.

[EDIT] Just updated my code as @Gregg suggested, but I got this error :

```
 *** glibc detected *** ./io2: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0974b008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b281)[0xb7673281]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6cad8)[0xb7674ad8]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb7677bbd]
./io2[0x80489c3]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb761ec76]
./io2[0x8048671]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 842293     /home/debianbox/posix/io/io2
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00000000 08:09 842293     /home/debianbox/posix/io/io2
0974b000-0976c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b74e2000-b74ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 12068      /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b74ff000-b7500000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 12068      /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7500000-b7521000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7521000-b7600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b7607000-b7608000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7608000-b7748000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 16133      /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.2.so 
b7748000-b774a000 r--p 0013f000 08:01 16133      /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.2.so 
b774a000-b774b000 rw-p 00141000 08:01 16133      /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.2.so 
b774b000-b774e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b775e000-b7760000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7760000-b7761000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7761000-b777c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 12335      /lib/ld-2.11.2.so 
b777c000-b777d000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 12335      /lib/ld-2.11.2.so 
b777d000-b777e000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 12335      /lib/ld-2.11.2.so 
bfe06000-bfe1b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Abandon
```

For an unknown reason, it fails at the free(spaces) line.

[EDIT] I finally correct my problem. @dmh200 suggested, i wrongly use the *size* variable and **strlen(f2)**. Useless question. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: And the error is what? Is size something else than 1?

Comment: The string literal `" "` is an array with 2 elements: namely `' '` and `'\0'`. Any attempt to read more that those 2 from the array is wrong. Try a loop.

Comment: The write function returns -1

Comment: what is 'f2'? you are using sizeof(f2) and size interchangeably but f2 isn't shown in your code example. if strlen(f2) is shorter than 'size' (or if 'size' is not initialized) you have a buffer overrun problem which is probably corrupting the heap, hence your gdb message. your code should first do 'size = strlen(f2)'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of `write()` must point to a buffer that contains (at least) the number of bytes specified in the `size` parameter.

The constant string `" "` contains *two* bytes only - a space and a trailing nul byte. Calling `write(fd, " ", size)` with `size > 2` is an error.

If you know you will always write less than say, 10 spaces, then you could:

```
write(fd, "          ", size);
```

If you don't know how many spaces you need, then you could dynamically allocate a buffer, fill it with spaces, and write that:

```
char *spaces = malloc(size);
memset(spaces, ' ', size);
write(fd, spaces, size);
free(spaces);
```